# Houseplants care tips

Tags: houseplants, indoors, watering

I am a new plant mom and have a variety of plants ( peace lilies, anthuriums, dracaena, pothos etc.) And I am very particular about watering, soil check and pruning etc.  I am leaving for a trip (10days) and am worried the plants may wilt or die by the time I'm back. Any tips/ ideas on how I can ensure they are healthy and watered while am away?